# Elasticsearch PKI security realm licensing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

Here in subscription page https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

Stated that **Encrypted communications** is under basic license.
However when I defined pki realm for client authentication, it didn't work until I enabled trial version.
Looked again on page and found **Custom authentication & authorization realms** is under platinum subscription.

My question is
Whether **encrypted communication** includes two way (mutual) authentication or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Pure mutual TLS authentication is under basic license, however if you have to associate roles for the user which is part of CN on certificate and not use user/password (native realm), you have to define pki realm which is under platinum subscription.

[Answers from ES support](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/pki-security-realm-lisence/273392)